# cache authorization token for AuthenticationContext

Tags: restful-authentication, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

Can I cache the token generated for a tenant, while creating the  GraphServiceClient and reuse it again, if so how long is the token valid? what causes it's expiration?
The code I have uses IAuthenticationProvider and implements

```
public async Task AuthenticateRequestAsync(HttpRequestMessage request)
    {   
        AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(url.ToString());
        ClientCredential creds = new ClientCredential(clientId, clientSecret);
        AuthenticationResult authResult = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync("https://graph.microsoft.com", creds);
        request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The Azure Active Directory Token Lifetimes are documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-configurable-token-lifetimes).

> **Default Limits**
>
> - Access Token Lifetime
>
>   - Affects: Access tokens, ID tokens, SAML2 tokens
>   - Default Lifetime: 1 hour
> - Refresh Token Max Inactive Time
>
>   - Affects: Refresh tokens
>   - Default Lifetime: 14 days
> - Single-Factor Refresh Token Max Age
>
>   - Affects: Refresh tokens (for any users)
>   - Default Lifetime: 90 days
> - Multi-Factor Refresh Token Max Age
>
>   - Affects: Refresh tokens (for any users)
>   - Default Lifetime: 90 days
> - Single-Factor Session Token Max Age
>
>   - Affects: Session tokens (persistent and nonpersistent)
>   - Default Lifetime: Until-revoked
> - Multi-Factor Session Token Max Age
>
>   - Affects: Session tokens (persistent and nonpersistent)
>   - Default Lifetime: Until-revoked